# Error: invalid environment block. Press any key to continue (Ubuntu 20.04 ZFS)

Tags: boot, grub2, 20.04

The error message appears immediately after the boot screen on purple background. Ubuntu 20.04 (ZFS) LTS.

```
error: invalid enviroment block.
Press any key to continue ...
```

not help

```
cd /boot/grub
rm grubenv
grub-editenv grubenv create
grub-editenv grubenv set default=0
grub-editenv grubenv list
update-grub
```

Howto fix?
each start takes 20 seconds longer
(thus ubuntu is the slowest starting operating system)

Amazing - i tested zfs recovery and scrubbing,
It works well both :)

But problem, other HDD install Linux ext4 Luks.

Comment: Please also append the contents of your ```/boot/grub/grubenv/```.

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs as a result of a corrupt memory location and so I would show you a way you can fix it from the initramfs prompt.

firstly type: **blkid** to list all partitions in the system

then you type: **fsck /dev/sdb8 -y** to enable the system fix any memory error of that selected partition.

finally just type: **reboot** to reboot the system and problem fixed!
**note: your partition may differ from mine so make sure to do it on your boot partition**

Answer (score 0):

Ok, resloved.
Delete other HDD other test Linux