# GRUB Error 'invalid environment block' on booting & updating Ubuntu Server 20.04

Tags: boot, grub2, dpkg

When I boot my Ubuntu 20.04 server (virtualbox vdi, local dev), I get the following error:

```
Error: invalid environment block.
press any key to continue....
```

Now, when I run updates, everything installs correctly, except for grub, which throws this error:

```
dpkg: error processing package grub-common (--configure):
 installed grub-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub2-common:
 grub2-common depends on grub-common (= 2.04-1ubuntu26.17); however:
  Package grub-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package grub2-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-pc-bin:
 grub-pc-bin depends on grub-common (= 2.04-1ubuntu26.17); however:
  Package grub-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package grub-pc-bin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-pc:
 grub-pc depends on grub-common (= 2.04-1ubuntu26.17); however:
  Package grub-common is not configured yet.
 grub-pc depends on grub2-common (= 2.04-1ubuntu26.17); however:
  Package grub2-common is not configured yet.
 grub-pc depends on grub-pc-bin (= 2.04-1ubuntu26.17); however:
  Package grub-pc-bin is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package grub-pc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-common
 grub2-common
 grub-pc-bin
 grub-pc
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**Solutions I've tried**

1. I booted the server from system disk and ran `e2fsck /dev/sda2 -y` as suggested in [Error: invalid environment block. Press any key to continue (Ubuntu 20.04 ZFS)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1264894/error-invalid-environment-block-press-any-key-to-continue-ubuntu-20-04-zfs), but no luck.
2. Running

   ```
   sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt --fix-broken install
   ```
3. Running

   ```
   dpkg --purge --force-depends grub-common && apt-get -f install
   ```

Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a corrupted `/boot/grub/grubenv`. A common source for this can be a hardware defect, or loose cable, or possibly turning off power while in grub.

Deleting the file and running `sudo grub-editenv list` while create an empty file, and allow you to continue.

related:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1946097

https://sarata.com/manpages/grub-editenv.1.html

Comment: short, sweet, effective... worked on first attempt... thanks for the helping hand.  FYI I am workin virtualbox.  The problem started after I used virtuabloox to compact my disk.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough information, but common things you can always try is:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

---

or this:

```
dpkg --purge --force-depends grub-common
apt-get -f install
```

---

or maybe simply this works:

```
apt update & apt-upgrade
```

Comment: swing and a miss... thx for trying... no effect... same errors